# How to print domain name in the curl output

Tags: linux, curl, xargs

I am using xargs and curl command to get the response from the list of domains in the input file.

```
xargs -n 1 curl -sS < input.txt 2>&1 | tee curltest
```

It is hard to find which domain out is which when it curls 10s of domains.

Tried verbose but it list so much trace information, but i am just looking for the domain name on top of the curl output. Is there a way to print the domain name on top of the curl response output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a short in-line shell script that outputs the URL and then does the call to `curl`:

```bsh
xargs -n 1 sh -c '
    printf "URL = %s\n" "$1"
    curl -sS "$1"' sh <input.txt 2>&1 |
tee curltest
```

Inside the `sh -c` script, the current URL read from `input.txt`, is available in `"$1"`.

Alternatively, don't use `xargs` at all and just loop over the URLs in the shell directly:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r url; do
    printf 'url = %s\n' "$url"
    curl -sS "$url"
done <input.txt 2>&1 |
tee curltest
```